# Passing NodeJS data to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a web application with a client that receives data from a server. I have the data in NodeJS, but I want to pass the data to a Javascript file. The Javascript file is included in a HTML file, so I can't make the files communicate with eachother.

I am new to NodeJS, so it can be a stupid question, but anyones help is appreciated

This is for a project where I need have a data stream, and I need to pass it into a web application. I tried to pass the data to different page inside my application and then I tried to get that data on that page inside my web application via Javascript, but I couldn't make that work. I'm not even sure if its possible at this point.

Comment: If you have a web application then you have some backend, why not make a get request to it from the javascript (by returning JSON)?

Comment: You can use the XMLHttpRequest for doing that, and if you have implemented jQuery on your front, you can use ajax. Your node server can't communicate with your front-end but your front-end can call your node server, so with a get request as said @tomerpacific before you can get your data. For that you have to open a route with your express app. Take a look on : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest and https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html

Comment: @BenoitChassignol Thanks I'll take a look!

Comment: Your front-end can in-fact communicate with the front-end, via a websocket!

Comment: @mHvNG Tell if it's all right for you i gonna put my comment as an answer.

Comment: @LeeBrindley I'll take a look at that to, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node server can't communicate with your front-end without a specific way of communication like [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), you have many other way to communicate with your front-end as node-server, take a look at server send event for example.

By the way your front-end can call your node server more easely with a get request as said @tomerpacific in comment.

For that you have to open a route with your express app. [Routing with express](https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html)
And for call it on a GET request, for that you can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), and if you have implemented jQuery on your front, you can use [Ajax jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).